# Warlords of Draenor: Status of Doomhammer

Tags: video-games, warcraft

Not sure if this would be a lore question or a straight-up game question, but I'll start here (feel free to move if needed). I don't think any of it is spoilerish, but if so tag it up for me as you see fit.

In the latest expansion for World of WarCraft, we find ourselves on an alternate version of Draenor where the orcs never drank Mannaroth's blood (which turned their brown skin to green) and became enslaved to The Burning Legion. The exception to this was Gul'dan, who had already drank the blood prior to Hellscream's refusal (shown in the opening cinematic).

While questing in Talador, we meet Ogrim Doomhammer, the orc who took over the Horde as Warchief after they invaded Azeroth. While I can reconcile Doomhammer being subordinate to Grom Hellscream (it was originally the other way around), I'm curious as to why Doomhammer is the only orc other than Gul'dan with green skin. Although other orcs seemed surprised to see Thrall's green skin, no mention is made of Doomhammer having green skin. Other members of the Shadow Council are allied with The Burning Legion, yet still have brown skin (indicating they never drank demon blood). Besides, under the circumstances I would think green skin would be a dead give-away as to who's with the Shadow Council and who's not, and therefore a liability.

Is this an oversight on Blizzard's part, or is there an in-game explanation for this?

Comment: id say its a mistake i saw this as well, and since he... is no longer a part of the game after you meet him i doubt well know why, originally guld'an and blackhand ran the horde, with doomhammer as his second in command, i wonder if doomhammer and blackhand had already drank the blood before grom stopped it.

Comment: blackhand and guldan lead the horde through the dark portal originally, with doomhammer as second in command, doomhammer however killed blackhand during the first war, and then retreated with the horde.

Comment: i also think im the only one who plays wow on here >.>

Comment: Ah, you're right - Doomhammer was the Warchief in the second game. I've been playing since Orcs & Humans but it's been a while.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised there aren't more WarCraft questions on here. It may have started as a LotR knockoff, but it's since developed a very rich & complex lore of its own.

Comment: then they added spaceships and retconned 20 years of lore, gg lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orgrim Doomhammer is not green in Warlords of Draenor, he's *gray*.

[image: Orgrim Doomhammer]

Orgrim is of the Blackrock Clan, a segment of orcs known for their paler, gray skin; some other Blackrock orcs with similar pigmentation are Eitrigg, Malkorok, and even Rend Blackhand.

[image: Eitrigg]

[image: Malkorok]

[image: Rend Blackhand]

It is commonly confused with green, due to the similarity of shades between it and the lighter shades of the deep green orcs that are seen elsewhere in the game.

[image: Thrall]

I'm not going to lie: Blizzard could *probably* have chosen a hue with less green in it to prevent this sort of misunderstanding.

Source: [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Orc)

Comment: Gray. I'll buy that.